# Is there an elegant way to replace if by something like switch when dealing with intervals?

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

Is there a way in .NET to replace a code where intervals are compared like

```
if (compare < 10)
        {
            // Do one thing
        }
        else if (10 <= compare && compare < 20)
        {
            // Do another thing
        }
        else if (20 <= compare && compare < 30)
        {
            // Do yet another thing
        }
        else
        {
            // Do nothing
        }
```

by something more elegant like a switch statement (I think in Javascript "case (<10)" works, but in c#)? Does anyone else find this code is ugly as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simplification: since these are all *else-if* instead of just *if*, you don't need to check the negation of the previous conditions.  I.e., this is equivalent to your code:

```
if (compare < 10)
{
    // Do one thing
}
else if (compare < 20)
{
    // Do another thing
}
else if (compare < 30)
{
    // Do yet another thing
}
else
{
    // Do nothing
}
```

Comment: True - why didn't R# see this? Why didn't I?

Answer (score 2):

Since you've already affirmed that `compare >= 10` after the first `if`, you really don't need the lower bound test on the second (or any of the other) `if`s...

It's not pretty, but `switch` was originally implemented by hashing in C, so that it was actually faster than an `if...else if` chain. Such an implementation doesn't translate well to general ranges, and that's also why only constant cases were allowed.

However, for the example you give you could actually do something like:

```
switch(compare/10) {
    case 0:
        // Do one thing
    break;
    case 1:
        // Do another thing
    break;
    case 2:
        // Do yet another thing
    break;
    default;
        // Do nothing
    break;
}
```

Comment: Regarding your `switch(compare/10)`, what if `compare` is negative?

Comment: @Justin, yeah, I thought about that after posting, but decided to ignore it... In which case you'd need an `if` at the front or `Math.Max(0, compare/10)` for the expression.

Comment: The intention of the question is more generic: are there general code  structures that cover this kind of thing and that apply as well if the intervals are irregular?

Comment: @Olaf, I tried to address that at least for why `switch` does not do that. C# is close to C, which doesn't tend to contain syntax that duplicates existing syntax. That leads to cludgy code sometimes, but it's also more likely that someone who "knows" C# should be able to read any code. In comparison, you have languages like perl, which has numerous ways to do the same thing but is sometimes difficult even for the person who wrote the code to decipher what exactly it's doing after some time has passed. With C#, you know what it's doing even if you don't remember why.

Comment: @Justin: excellent point. Never gave that much thought. Then again one could argue that the switch statement already duplicates simple if-else structures. Why not expand that duplication a little further?

Comment: @Olaf, yes, `if`s can be used instead of `switch`, but as I said, a `switch` can usually be handled with hashing, and the best way to let the compiler know that is possible is to create a new syntax for it. Especially in the days of text interfaces, menus prompting a text input and command-line options were very commonly used, and so making such things as efficient as possible was probably enough of a concern to add additional syntax to the language. Also, C allows fall through, which would require duplicate code or `goto`s with `if`s.

Comment: @jswolf19: Then I consider this question closed, basically with a "No" but with lots of interesting information. Thanks everybody. (And sorry, I confused jswolf19 and Justin in some of my comments)